# Virtual Hosts are acting really strange

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have two domains, `mycommunitysite.com` and `mypersonalblog.com`

When I go to `mypersonalblog.com`, everything works. When I go to `mycommunitysite.com`, it also goes to the `mypersonalblog.com` front page. If I go to `mycommunitysite.com/forum`, it goes to the forum subdirectory of `mycommunitysite.com` as expected.

The virtual host directives in apache look like this, my server is running CentOS, if that makes a difference:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mycommunitysite
    ServerName mycommunitysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mycommunitysite.com
    ErrorLog logs/mycommunitysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypersonalblog
    ServerName mypersonalblog.com
    ServerAlias www.mypersonalblog.com
    ErrorLog logs/mypersonalblog.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The output of `apachectl -S`

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 108.166.78.198 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myweddingsite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
         port 80 namevhost myweddingsite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
         port 80 namevhost clientsite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1025)
         port 80 namevhost mycommunitysite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1035)
         port 80 namevhost mypersonalblog.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1053)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Do you have both the default and a virtual host for "myweddingsite.com"??

Answer (score 1):

Add a global directive `ServerName www.example.com` to `httpd.conf`
Be sure you're DNS has forward and reverse looking working correctly for all domain names and IPs.

Comment: I added the ServerName directive, which has stopped the complaining about FQDN on apache, but my problem still persists. How do I know if Forward and Reverse Lookup is working correctly>

Comment: `dig forward.name.example.com` and `dig -x 12.34.56.78`. If you can not get DNS configured correctly for whatever reason, adding the relevant entries to the servers `/etc/hosts` file will cheat the server into thinking that you have DNS configured.

Answer (score 0):

If `/etc/hosts` is missing an entry for the IP that Apache is trying to bind to, it will complain about not being able to determine the FQDN.  This seems to affect VirtualHosts.